# Unmet dependencies in Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, apt, dependencies, software-sources, codecs

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
       gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg: Depends: libavcodec-extra-53 (>= 4:0.7-1) but    4:0.7.2.1ubuntu2 is to be installed
                         Depends: libavformat-extra-53 (>= 4:0.7-1) but 4:0.7.2.1ubuntu2 is to be installed
                         Depends: libavutil-extra-51 (>= 4:0.7-1) but 4:0.7.2.1ubuntu2 is to be installed
                         Depends: libc6 (>= 2.7) but 2.15-0ubuntu10 is to be installed
                         Depends: libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.24.0) but 2.32.3-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
                         Depends: libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0 (>= 0.10.31) but 0.10.36-1ubuntu0.1 is to be installed
                         Depends: libgstreamer0.10-0 (>= 0.10.31) but 0.10.36-1ubuntu1 is to be installed
                         Depends: liborc-0.4-0 (>= 1:0.4.14) but 1:0.4.16-1ubuntu2 is to be installed
                         Depends: libpostproc-extra-52 (>= 4:0.7-1) but 4:0.7.2.1ubuntu2 is to be installed
                         Depends: libswscale-extra-2 (>= 4:0.7-1) but 4:0.7.2.1ubuntu2 is to be installed gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg:i386:    Depends: libavcodec-extra-53 (>= 4:0.7-1) but 4:0.7.2.1ubuntu2 is to   be installed
                              Depends: libavformat-extra-53 (>= 4:0.7-1) but 4:0.7.2.1ubuntu2 is to be installed
                              Depends: libavutil-extra-51 (>= 4:0.7-1) but 4:0.7.2.1ubuntu2 is to be installed
                              Depends: libc6 (>= 2.7) but 2.15-0ubuntu10 is to be installed
                              Depends: libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.24.0) but 2.32.3-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
                              Depends: libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0 (>= 0.10.31) but 0.10.36-1ubuntu0.1 is to be installed
                              Depends: libgstreamer0.10-0 (>= 0.10.31) but 0.10.36-1ubuntu1 is to be installed
                              Depends: liborc-0.4-0 (>= 1:0.4.14) but 1:0.4.16-1ubuntu2 is to be installed
                              Depends: libpostproc-extra-52 (>= 4:0.7-1) but 4:0.7.2.1ubuntu2 is to be installed
                              Depends: libswscale-extra-2 (>= 4:0.7-1) but 4:0.7.2.1ubuntu2 is to be installed



       Package dependencies cannot be resolved
       This error could be caused by required additional software packages    which are missing or not installable. Furthermore there could be a    conflict between software packages which are not allowed to be    installed at the same time.
```

I have tried to follow every instruction from [here](http://www.linuxforums.org/forum/debian-linux/110983-solved-unmet-dependencies.html) and it has still not helped me.

What is the problem and how do I fix it ?

**Edit:**
My problem is that I can't install Gstreamer ffmpeg video plug-in 
codecs to play .mpeg, .divx, .mpeg4, .ac3, .wmv and .asf files

Comment: Please try a `sudo apt-get update` first, and then see if you still get this error.

Comment: Additionally would have helped if you mentioned what your are trying to install

Comment: i dont have any problem with update .. what my problem is i cant install 
Gstreamer ffmpeg video plugin 
codecs to play mpeg , divx , mpeg4 , ac3 ,wmv and asf files

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You appear to be using very outdated libraries, for example "libavcodec-extra-53 (>= 4:0.7-1) but **4:0.7.2.1ubuntu2** is to be installed". That version was released in 12.04 dev on 2011-12-26 and has been Superseded numerous times.

The current 12.04 version is 4:0.8.3ubuntu0.12.04.1) precise-security

So open software sources,  `software-properties-gtk` & make sure that under `Ubuntu Software` the 1st 4 are checked & under `Updates` the 1st. 2 are checked

Then update your sources  & see

Comment: i do what you say but its still giving the same Unmet dependencies ?

Comment: Could you open up software sources, switch to the `main server`, the run `sudo apt-get clean && sudo apt-get update`. Post the results in `ubuntu pastebin` & link in your question

Comment: For me this doesn't work.. :/

Comment: The mian server trick worked, I do not know why don't the other servers update regularly. I was using a PK server and had been trying to solve the issue for 2 days. Set it to main-server and it worked.