# Video codec dependencies not met?

Tags: 12.04, video, dependencies, codecs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I resolve unmet dependencies?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies)

After trying to run a .M4A and a .MP4 (aren't they same thing?) I get a message saying I need to install extra codecs. When attempting to do this, I get an error window stating 'dependencies not met' for the codecs. The error report is this:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:

```
gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg: Depends: libavcodec-extra-53 (>= 4:0.7.3-1) but<br> 4:0.8.3ubuntu0.12.04.1 is to be installed<br>
                      Depends: libavformat-extra-53 (>= 4:0.7.3-1) but 4:0.8.3ubuntu0.12.04.1 is to be installed
                      Depends: libavutil-extra-51 (>= 4:0.7.3-1) but 4:0.8.3ubuntu0.12.04.1 is to be installed
                      Depends: libc6 (>= 2.7) but 2.15-0ubuntu10 is to be installed
                      Depends: libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.31.2) but 2.32.3-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
                      Depends: libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0 (>= 0.10.31) but 0.10.36-1ubuntu0.1 is to be installed
                      Depends: libgstreamer0.10-0 (>= 0.10.31) but 0.10.36-1ubuntu1 is to be installed
                      Depends: liborc-0.4-0 (>= 1:0.4.16) but 1:0.4.16-1ubuntu2 is to be installed
                      Depends: libpostproc-extra-52 (>= 4:0.7.3-1) but 4:0.8.3ubuntu0.12.04.1 is to be installed
                      Depends: libswscale-extra-2 (>= 4:0.7.3-1) but 4:0.8.3ubuntu0.12.04.1 is to be installed gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg:i386: Depends: libavcodec-extra-53 (>= 4:0.7.3-1) but 4:0.8.3ubuntu0.12.04.1 is to be installed
                           Depends: libavformat-extra-53 (>= 4:0.7.3-1) but 4:0.8.3ubuntu0.12.04.1 is to be installed
                           Depends: libavutil-extra-51 (>= 4:0.7.3-1) but 4:0.8.3ubuntu0.12.04.1 is to be installed
                           Depends: libc6 (>= 2.7) but 2.15-0ubuntu10 is to be installed
                           Depends: libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.31.2) but 2.32.3-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
                           Depends: libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0 (>= 0.10.31) but 0.10.36-1ubuntu0.1 is to be installed
                           Depends: libgstreamer0.10-0 (>= 0.10.31) but 0.10.36-1ubuntu1 is to be installed
                           Depends: liborc-0.4-0 (>= 1:0.4.16) but 1:0.4.16-1ubuntu2 is to be installed
                           Depends: libpostproc-extra-52 (>= 4:0.7.3-1) but 4:0.8.3ubuntu0.12.04.1 is to be installed
                           Depends: libswscale-extra-2 (>= 4:0.7.3-1) but 4:0.8.3ubuntu0.12.04.1 is to be installed
```

Also, when trying to install system updates to packages it comes up with a error window from 'backhand_helper.py' says 'Packaging System is broken' and asks me to uninstall extra 3rd-party ppas. Clicking details says:
`

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:

libapt-pkg4.12: Depends: libc6 (>= 2.15) but 2.15-0ubuntu10 is installed
                Depends: libgcc1 (>= 1:4.1.1) but 1:4.6.3-1ubuntu5 is installed
                Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 4.6) but 4.6.3-1ubuntu5 is installed
                Depends: zlib1g (>= 1:1.2.2.3) but 1:1.2.3.4.dfsg-3ubuntu4 is installed
libapt-pkg4.12:i386: Depends: libc6 (>= 2.15) but 2.15-0ubuntu10 is installed
                     Depends: libgcc1 (>= 1:4.1.1) but 1:4.6.3-1ubuntu5 is installed
                     Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 4.6) but 4.6.3-1ubuntu5 is installed
                     Depends: zlib1g (>= 1:1.2.3.3.dfsg) but 1:1.2.3.4.dfsg-3ubuntu4 is installed
```

Thanks :))

Comment: I am voting to close this question as a duplicate since you have successfully solved your problem and the general instructions in the canonical question should be more than enough for the passers-by.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras` worked for me. It installed a lot of other stuff, but it gets the job done.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running Ubuntu 32-bit, run this on Terminal:

```
sudo apt-get -y install gstreamer0.10-pitfdll gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad-multiverse gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly-multiverse
```

If you are running Ubuntu 64-bit, run this on Terminal:

```
sudo apt-get -y install gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad-multiverse gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly-multiverse
```

Answer (score 1):

Run `sudo apt-get update` first.

Then you can successfully install gstreamer plugins.

As @ThiagoPonte said, install all gstreamer packages, so you wouldn't need to install extra codecs again.

Also check similar question: 
[Unmet dependencies in Ubuntu 12.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/177468/unmet-dependencies-ubuntu-12-04)

Comment: I ran `sudo apt-get install -f` because `sudo apt-get update` didn't do anything. It came up with an error window suggesting me to use the first code and this came up: `E: Internal Error, No file name for libapt-pkg4.12`

Comment: The window says 'The Package System is Broken' and wants me to uninstall 3rd-party ppas. Details show this:

Comment: It won't fit here so I'll include it above in the question description

Answer (score 0):

First Update the system By follwing command in terminal

> sudo apt-get update

Fix dependencies using

> sudo apt-get install -f

Comment: E: Internal Error, No file name for libapt-pkg4.12