# Ubuntu 14.04 64bit - 'GStreamer ffmpeg video plugin' problem

Tags: video, ffmpeg, gstreamer

I can't install gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg on Ubuntu 14.04

[image]

Comment: try **apt-get install libgstreamer0.10-dev libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-dev** -----------source http://superuser.com/questions/124943/how-can-i-resolve-gstreamer-dependencies-in-ubuntu

Comment: tried it does not help

Comment: see here http://askubuntu.com/questions/192832/video-codec-dependencies-not-met

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg` is not supported on 14.04 at this time. See [this page](http://www.webupd8.org/2014/03/get-firefox-and-phonon-gstreamer-to.html) for details and workarounds.

Answer (score 7):

Doug McMahon has a launchpad PPA for Ubuntu Multimedia for Trusty [here](https://launchpad.net/~mc3man/+archive/ubuntu/trusty-media) where you can view the packages he has available.

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:mc3man/trusty-media
```

and

```
sudo apt-get update
```

after that do

```
sudo apt-get install ffmpeg gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg gstreamer0.10-fluendo-mp3 gstreamer0.10-gnonlin gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad-multiverse gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly totem-plugins-extra gstreamer-tools ubuntu-restricted-extras libxine1-ffmpeg gxine mencoder mpeg2dec vorbis-tools id3v2 mpg321 mpg123 libflac++6 totem-mozilla icedax tagtool easytag id3tool lame nautilus-script-audio-convert libmad0 libjpeg-progs flac faac faad sox ffmpeg2theora libmpeg2-4 uudeview flac libmpeg3-1 mpeg3-utils mpegdemux liba52-0.7.4-dev libquicktime2
```

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you have all the appropriate software sources enabled under "`Software and Updates`" because,I don't believe those proprietary codecs are in the "main" repo. After you double check and enable those sources, run:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Then try to install it again.

[image: Screenshot of my sources]

Comment: checked all of them, it does not work too